# import pyodbc, No module name 'pyodbc'

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pyodbc

I am pretty new to all this so please bear with me.

I am trying to deploy my code in AWS Elastic-Bean Stalk and my code has pyodbc package to fetch data from the database. The database is deployed on Microsoft Azure and it's connected to the code. After deploying code to Elastic-bean it's showing error

```
import pyodbc no module name pyodbc
```

I have checked the requirement.txt file and it has latest version of pyodbc package. I did update all the versions that I have imported. There are students who have done the same process(database on Azure and Code on AWS ElasticBean Stack) and its running fine. My code is running perfectly fine on the local machine.

any leads ???

Answer (score 0):

The install `pyodbc` may be failing, thus its not getting installed.

The reason is, that on EB for Amazon Linux 2, you need to have `gcc-c++` and `unixODBC-devel` as prerequisites for `pyodbc`.

Thus in your `.ebextentaions` you can add a config file `.ebextentaions/10_packages.config` with the content of:

```
packages: 
  yum:
    gcc-c++: []
    unixODBC-devel: []
```